# How can I change Vuetify's primary text color?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In a few places, vuetify sets text color to the "primary color" defined in its theme (eg. hilighting selected drop down menus). With my company's colors, this looks ugly. How can I set this to be different?

From what I can tell, this comes from these css rules:

```
.v-application.primary--text {
    color: #0064a2 !important;
    caret-color: #0064a2 !important;
}
```

When I change those, I can make the text color look nice. Unfortunately, they're generated by vuetify and marked as `!important`, so I can't seem to change them outside of the browser inspector.

I can add something like `'primary--text': 'color: #FF00FF'` to the style theme, but that changes the background color, not the text color.

[Here's a codepen example](https://codepen.io/kenkron/pen/jOEaqoB?editors=1010)

I could use vuetify's themes exclusively for text, and set the rest of the element colors manually, but this doesn't seem to be their intended use. What should I do to change the text color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a class to the app and create a more-specific CSS rule like so (this example doesn't actually run here, but you can copy it over to your codepen):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify({
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {

          // Color is applied to selected drop down item
          primary: '#0064A2',
          
          // Uncomment this to make things worse
          // 'primary--text': '#FF00FF'
        }
      }
    }
  }),
})
```

```css
.my-app.v-application .primary--text {
    color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app class="my-app">
    <!--Click the dropdown to see ugly colors-->
    <v-select :items="[undefined]"/>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, and it works [codepen](https://codepen.io/kenkron/pen/vYEWKpL). I still think vuetify should handle this differently, but this is a pretty clean workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and Roy's answer guided me to this solution:

```
.my-app.v-application .primary--text {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

This way, you aren't screwing up styling for other items that are using the primary color.